# Does CentOS 6 have a kernel-module-extra equivalent?

Tags: centos, kernel-modules

I am attempting to activate and use my TPM module, but all online instructions suggest I install kernel-modules-extras package.  The problem is, I cannot find this package type for CentOS 6.  Is this type of extras in a different package?

What is the best way to install tpm modules for use in CentOS 6?

Answer (score 1):

i believe your looking for the tpm-tools and trousers rpms.  It should be available via normal CentOS repositories.

Comment: I added these both to the OS and they do not add tpm.ko, tpm_bios.ko, or tpm_tis.ko which are required for full support :/